# Gridview Linkbutton Code behind

Tags: asp.net

Until now, I was working with VS 2003 and recently migrated to VS 2008.  I am facing some peculiar problems.

In Vs 2003,I had a Datagrid, and one of the field was `ButtonField`(Link button).  It was not a template field.  The user clicks on the field and some data gets generated.

I have written a code, in Vb, like this, on `dg_ItemCommand`:

```
Strid = Ctype(e.commandsource,linkbutton).text
```

Now i want to use same method,for the gridview (I think datagrid is gridview in 2008).  I wrote a code like this on `dg_Rowcomand`

```
Private Sub dgSampleCustomer_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgSampleCustomer.RowCommand 
  Try 
    Dim strid As String 
    Dim i As Integer
    strid = CType(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).Text
...
```

It is throwing a error.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to
>   type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField'.

Can anybody help me out!

Comment: DataGrid is still there in VS 2008, but GridView is a new control with .NET 2.0.

Comment: The error is not coming from that line; It says you are casting something to type ButtonField, but I don't see that above.  It must be from somewhere else.

Comment: Did not add any other code.This is what i wrote

Private Sub dgSampleCustomer_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgSampleCustomer.RowCommand Try Dim strid As String

        Dim i As Integer



        strid = CType(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).Text

Comment: Then the problem is the Gridview changes everything around and e.CommandSource cannot be cast to the LinkButton...

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering why you are trying to cast the command source to a LinkButton? If you would like to attach or otherwise send some kind of row-specific information to your button handler, you are able to do this with the CommandName and CommandArgument attributes of the ButtonField.

Like:

```
 <asp:Gridview ID="...">
 ...
 <columns>
                <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
                  commandname="Generate"
                  text="Generate"/>
 ...
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This will be retrievable in the event handler by using:

```
if(e.CommandName=="Generate")
{
  // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
  // property to an Integer.
  string rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

UPDATE: (use DataKeys)
Since e.CommandArgument returns a row index, and you want the ID, use the DataKeys collection, first add your ID column to the DataKeyNames collection...

```
<asp:GridView ... DataKeyNames="ID">
```

... and then retrieve the values from the DataKeys collection, like:

```
GridView sourceGridView = (GridView) e.CommandSource;
rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
strID = sourceGridView.DataKeys[rowIndex]["ID"];
```

Comment: I have Rewritten my code,but the Strid returns a blank value.Where as ,the 0th cell contains value of my Id = "1"   If e.CommandName = "Click" Then
                i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
                Dim SelectedRow As GridViewRow = dgSampleCustomer.Rows(i)
                Dim contactcell As TableCell = SelectedRow.Cells(0)
                strid = contactcell.Text


            End If

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, the CommandArgument by default is the Row Index (starting with 0) of the button that triggered the event. If you don't want to use a TemplateField (which allows you to set the CommandArgument explicitly). Go ahead and use the DataKey stuff, I'll update my example.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the source of the command is the GridView itself, not the button you are clicking.  What you probably want to do is set this value you are looking for in the "CommandArgument" property of the Linkbutton.  The markup would look something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton" runat="server"
    CommandName="MyCommandName"
    CommandArgument="MySpecialValue"
    Text="Click Me" />
```

Then in the event you would simply:

```
' strid = "MySpecialValue"
strid = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
```

Instead of pulling the ID from the name of the control, you can now easily get it from the command.  CommandName is optional in this particular case, but comes in handy if you have multiple buttons on a grid that do different things, such as "Edit" and "Delete".  Then you can use the command name to handle each command in their own way in the same event:

```
If (e.CommandName = "Edit") Then
    ' Do Some Edit Code
End If
```

Comment: using this,strid = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
My strid is return value as "0",but my id value is "1"

Comment: Are you actually setting the CommandArgument property on the LinkButton?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your rowcommand event

```
Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)      
Dim row = dg.Rows(index)      
'find your linkbutton in template field (replace "lnkBtn" with your's)
Dim myLinkButton = CType(row.FindControl("lnkBtn"), LinkButton)
Dim strid As String = myLinkButton.Text
```

Let me know if it helps.